# ibm bluemix watson speech to text service

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, watson

How to connect watson speech to text service to my bluemix app and after how can we configure service? I need full detailed speech to text service document how we can connect and use.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a sample Bluemix application here:

link: [Speech to Text Browser Application](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-nodejs)

It's a Node.js Application for the IBM Watson Speech-to-Text Service. You can run the app in Bluemix or local.

Comment: I created application and added service in bluemix, now I need to call watson API. I have code, I placed that in my app.js and to convert audio file to text file. I couldn't able to convert, Please help me with that!

Comment: var speech_to_text = new SpeechToTextV1 ({
                         ^

ReferenceError: SpeechToTextV1 is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manoj Reddy\Desktop\myexamplestt\app.js:29:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3

Answer (score 1):

The landing page of the Watson STT service has pointers to all the resources including full documentation, sdks, sample code, etc:

https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/speech-to-text/

Comment: Thank you Daniel! Placed speech to text watson service API in app.js and gave service credentials. I try to run code but I am getting error not able to convert audio file to text. Please help me with that pls

Comment: var speech_to_text = new SpeechToTextV1 ({
                         ^

ReferenceError: SpeechToTextV1 is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manoj Reddy\Desktop\myexamplestt\app.js:29:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at this sample application using web sockets and Python [STT using Web Sockets and Python](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-websockets-python).

Another good resource is the [Speech Services Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/RedbookAbstracts/sg248388.html).  For more general kinds of technical information, there is a curated GitHub project called [The Watson Landing Page](https://github.com/dtoczala/watson-landing-page) with a curated set of links and information on the various Watson services.

Comment: Hi, Thank for sharing book! I used Watson API to call service.I just copied code and added to app.js and gave speech to text service credentials.I did everything as per document after that I  am getting some space error and I cleared that too, Still I am not able to convert text file. Please help me with that code part. Thank you in advance